# Enable COPY_ONLY Backup Via DISKSHADOW Command Prompt

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2019, vss, windows-server-2022

#### Introduction

I'm experiencing weird behaviour on a virtualised (ESXi) Windows Server 2022 running SQL Server 2019 when the VMware conducts a snapshot of the server. It doesn't log the snapshot in the **msdb** database.

On all our other SQL Server 2019 servers, when the ESXi host performs a VMware snapshot of the Windows Server with SQL Server 2019, then the **Volume Shadow Copy** service of Windows will be activated and this will trigger the **SQL Server VSS Writer** service. The SQL Server instance will duly note that a **is_copy_only** and **is_snapshot** backup was created for all databases of the instance.

On the Windows Server 2022 with SQL Server 2019 instance running there are no entries in the **msdb** backup  when VMware performs a snapshot. **Nothing**. This means there are no entries in the **ERRORLOG** that contain `I/O is frozen on database <database name>. No user action is required. However...` and `I/O was resumed on database <database name>. No user action is required.` messages.

In order to pinpoint the issue I started looking at the Microsoft articles on the [`VSSADMIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/vssadmin) and the [`DISKSHADOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc772172(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) command line tools. I supplemented my reading with the Microsoft article on [VSS & SQL Writer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-vss-writer-backup-guide?view=sql-server-ver16) which has some additional information on how the Volume Shadow Copies are initiated, etc.

#### Applying My Acquired Knowledge

I issued the following commands to create a valid, consistent Microsoft Volume Shadow Copy Snapshot of the quirky Windows Server 2022:

```
C:\Windows\system32>diskshadow
Microsoft DiskShadow version 1.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation
On computer:  SERVERNAME13,  22.07.2022 14:48:50


DISKSHADOW> set
Current context: VOLATILE
Current options: <none>
Verbose mode:    OFF
Metadata file:   <default>

No Diskshadow aliases are currently defined in the environment.

DISKSHADOW> set verbose on

DISKSHADOW> writer verify "SqlServerWriter"

DISKSHADOW> set metadata c:\temp\diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab

DISKSHADOW> begin backup

DISKSHADOW> add volume c: alias SYSTEM

DISKSHADOW> add volume e: alias SQLDATA

DISKSHADOW> add volume f: alias SQLLOGS

DISKSHADOW> add volume g: alias SQLTEMP

DISKSHADOW> add volume h: alias ADHOC

DISKSHADOW> create
```

This produced the following output, which shows us that the databases will be indeed included in the snapshot and be consistent:

> ```
>  Excluding writer "BITS Writer", because all of its components have been excluded.
>  Excluding writer "Shadow Copy Optimization Writer", because all of its components have been excluded.
>  Component "\BCD\BCD" from writer "ASR Writer" is excluded from backup,
>  because it requires volume  which is not in the shadow copy set.
>  All components from writer "SqlServerWriter" are selected.
>  
>  * Including writer "Task Scheduler Writer":
>          + Adding component: \TasksStore
>  
>  * Including writer "VSS Metadata Store Writer":
>          + Adding component: \WriterMetadataStore
>  
>  * Including writer "Performance Counters Writer":
>          + Adding component: \PerformanceCounters
>  
>  * Including writer "System Writer":
>          + Adding component: \System Files
>          + Adding component: \Win32 Services Files
>  
>  * Including writer "SqlServerWriter":
>          + Adding component: \SERVERNAME13\WSUS\master
>          + Adding component: \SERVERNAME13\WSUS\model
>          + Adding component: \SERVERNAME13\WSUS\msdb
>          + Adding component: \SERVERNAME13\WSUS\TVDTools
>          + Adding component: \SERVERNAME13\WSUS\SUSDB
>  
>  * Including writer "COM+ REGDB Writer":
>          + Adding component: \COM+ REGDB
>  
>  * Including writer "ASR Writer":
>          + Adding component: \ASR\ASR
>          + Adding component: \Volumes\Volume{0ae0e5e3-28e7-4d48-a0cc-be0fe93cc972}
>          + Adding component: \Volumes\Volume{5ff0815f-0548-42b5-9ab4-695abd5ca4fb}
>          + Adding component: \Volumes\Volume{13593a85-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}
>          + Adding component: \Volumes\Volume{994f9685-3bd3-4332-9450-2fa867bfd88b}
>          + Adding component: \Volumes\Volume{08659769-e6dc-4806-9caa-66b472f4ff12}
>          + Adding component: \Volumes\Volume{4d6aa966-9c7c-4a45-b9fb-74b82d27c9ba}
>          + Adding component: \Volumes\Volume{604630a9-6906-4d65-b522-efa9bce54b33}
>          + Adding component: \Volumes\Volume{90a44505-8b5c-46b9-a93c-17d109bb1b48}
>          + Adding component: \Disks\harddisk6
>          + Adding component: \Disks\harddisk3
>          + Adding component: \Disks\harddisk0
>          + Adding component: \Disks\harddisk4
>          + Adding component: \Disks\harddisk1
>          + Adding component: \Disks\harddisk5
>          + Adding component: \Disks\harddisk2
>  
>  * Including writer "Registry Writer":
>          + Adding component: \Registry
>  
>  * Including writer "WMI Writer":
>          + Adding component: \WMI
>  
>  Alias SYSTEM for shadow ID {d0dfc934-16f2-4545-8bed-f6ea4c39feb0} set as environment variable.
>  Alias SQLDATA for shadow ID {5c3890d3-fcca-4e97-bbc2-bcc0bf89e94a} set as environment variable.
>  Alias SQLLOGS for shadow ID {f2372742-d824-4049-8b11-6b7df6d4496c} set as environment variable.
>  Alias SQLTEMP for shadow ID {bd0cb807-87b3-4996-ae2c-8a37dc0b9ca7} set as environment variable.
>  Alias ADHOC for shadow ID {3db064ac-c8b1-4370-8d72-b4e5f567c62c} set as environment variable.
>  Alias VSS_SHADOW_SET for shadow set ID {80875036-e760-415e-a78f-79d61f699d4b} set as environment variable.
>  Inserted file Manifest.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file BCDocument.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file WM0.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file WM1.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file WM2.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file WM3.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file WM4.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file WM5.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file WM6.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file WM7.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file WM8.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file WM9.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file WM10.xml into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  Inserted file Dis7D66.tmp into .cab file diskshadow_c_e_f_g_h.cab
>  
>  Querying all shadow copies with the shadow copy set ID {80875036-e760-415e-a78f-79d61f699d4b}
>  
>          * Shadow copy ID = {d0dfc934-16f2-4545-8bed-f6ea4c39feb0}               %SYSTEM%
>                  - Shadow copy set: {80875036-e760-415e-a78f-79d61f699d4b}       %VSS_SHADOW_SET%
>                  - Original count of shadow copies = 5
>                  - Original volume name: \\?\Volume{0ae0e5e3-28e7-4d48-a0cc-be0fe93cc972}\ [C:\]
>                  - Creation time: 22.07.2022 14:50:23
>                  - Shadow copy device name: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1
>                  - Originating machine: SERVERNAME13.DOMAIN.TLD
>                  - Service machine: SERVERNAME13.DOMAIN.TLD
>                  - Not exposed
>                  - Provider ID: {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}
>                  - Attributes:  Auto_Release Differential
>  
>          * Shadow copy ID = {5c3890d3-fcca-4e97-bbc2-bcc0bf89e94a}               %SQLDATA%
>                  - Shadow copy set: {80875036-e760-415e-a78f-79d61f699d4b}       %VSS_SHADOW_SET%
>                  - Original count of shadow copies = 5
>                  - Original volume name: \\?\Volume{604630a9-6906-4d65-b522-efa9bce54b33}\ [E:\]
>                  - Creation time: 22.07.2022 14:50:23
>                  - Shadow copy device name: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy2
>                  - Originating machine: SERVERNAME13.DOMAIN.TLD
>                  - Service machine: SERVERNAME13.DOMAIN.TLD
>                  - Not exposed
>                  - Provider ID: {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}
>                  - Attributes:  Auto_Release Differential
>  
>          * Shadow copy ID = {f2372742-d824-4049-8b11-6b7df6d4496c}               %SQLLOGS%
>                  - Shadow copy set: {80875036-e760-415e-a78f-79d61f699d4b}       %VSS_SHADOW_SET%
>                  - Original count of shadow copies = 5
>                  - Original volume name: \\?\Volume{4d6aa966-9c7c-4a45-b9fb-74b82d27c9ba}\ [F:\]
>                  - Creation time: 22.07.2022 14:50:23
>                  - Shadow copy device name: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy3
>                  - Originating machine: SERVERNAME13.DOMAIN.TLD
>                  - Service machine: SERVERNAME13.DOMAIN.TLD
>                  - Not exposed
>                  - Provider ID: {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}
>                  - Attributes:  Auto_Release Differential
>  
>          * Shadow copy ID = {bd0cb807-87b3-4996-ae2c-8a37dc0b9ca7}               %SQLTEMP%
>                  - Shadow copy set: {80875036-e760-415e-a78f-79d61f699d4b}       %VSS_SHADOW_SET%
>                  - Original count of shadow copies = 5
>                  - Original volume name: \\?\Volume{08659769-e6dc-4806-9caa-66b472f4ff12}\ [G:\]
>                  - Creation time: 22.07.2022 14:50:23
>                  - Shadow copy device name: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy4
>                  - Originating machine: SERVERNAME13.DOMAIN.TLD
>                  - Service machine: SERVERNAME13.DOMAIN.TLD
>                  - Not exposed
>                  - Provider ID: {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}
>                  - Attributes:  Auto_Release Differential
>  
>          * Shadow copy ID = {3db064ac-c8b1-4370-8d72-b4e5f567c62c}               %ADHOC%
>                  - Shadow copy set: {80875036-e760-415e-a78f-79d61f699d4b}       %VSS_SHADOW_SET%
>                  - Original count of shadow copies = 5
>                  - Original volume name: \\?\Volume{994f9685-3bd3-4332-9450-2fa867bfd88b}\ [H:\]
>                  - Creation time: 22.07.2022 14:50:23
>                  - Shadow copy device name: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy5
>                  - Originating machine: SERVERNAME13.DOMAIN.TLD
>                  - Service machine: SERVERNAME13.DOMAIN.TLD
>                  - Not exposed
>                  - Provider ID: {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}
>                  - Attributes:  Auto_Release Differential
>  
>  Number of shadow copies listed: 5
> ```

I then ended the Volume Shadow Copy with:

```
DISKSHADOW> end backup

DISKSHADOW> exit
```

#### Confirming Snapshot Backup

Looking at the information in the **msdb** database, I was able to confirm that the databases had indeed been backed up:

> ```
> +---------------+-------------------------+------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
> | database_name |    backup_start_date    | type | backup_type | device_type_desc | is_copy_only | is_snapshot |
> +---------------+-------------------------+------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
> | model         | 2022-07-22 14:50:21.000 | D    | Full        | Virtual Device   |            0 |           1 |
> | msdb          | 2022-07-22 14:50:21.000 | D    | Full        | Virtual Device   |            0 |           1 |
> | SUSDB         | 2022-07-22 14:50:21.000 | D    | Full        | Virtual Device   |            0 |           1 |
> | master        | 2022-07-22 14:50:21.000 | D    | Full        | Virtual Device   |            0 |           1 |
> +---------------+-------------------------+------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
> ```

#### Problem

However, the database backups created with the `DISKSHADOW` CLU are not marked as **is_copy_only**. This is bad because a snapshot backup shouldn't break the backup chain. The VMware snaphsot is capable of creating backups with **is_copy_only** and **is_snapshot**.

Reading the [SQL Server Backup Applications - Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS) and SQL Writer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-vss-writer-backup-guide?view=sql-server-ver16) article I saw that there is the possibility of setting the backups to **COPY_ONLY**:

<sub>(**emphasis** mine)</sub>

> During the backup discovery phase, the SQL writer will indicate its capability to do a copy-only backup by setting the supported backup schema option VSS_BS_COPY using the IVssCreateWriterMetadata::SetBackupSchema call. **The requestor (*in my case the diskshadow CLU*)** can set the backup type as a copy-only backup by setting the **VSS_BACKUP_TYPE** option as **VSS_BT_COPY** with the call IVssBackupComponents::SetBackupState.

### Questions

1. Can I set the option `VSS_BACKUP_TYPE` to `VSS_BT_COPY` in the `DISKSHADOW` command-line utility?
2. Is there any other way to configure the **SQL Server VSS Writer** to create **COPY_ONLY** backups when manually creating a Volume Shadow Copy as I am doing?